# Usar una única función Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo este código:

```js
function celular(){ 
 $("#celu").css("display", "inline-block")  }   
function email(){ 
 $("#mail").css("display", "inline-block")  }
function telefono(){ 
 $("#fono").css("display", "inline-block")  }
function gmail(){ 
 $("#gma").css("display", "inline-block")  }

function Mouseva() {
 $("#celu").css("display", "none")  }
function Mouseva1() {
 $("#mail").css("display", "none")  }
function Mouseva2() {
 $("#fono").css("display", "none")  }
function Mouseva3() {
 $("#gma").css("display", "none")  }
```

```html
 <div class="social">
  <ul id="social">
   <li><a href="mailto:nmpiovano@gmail.com" class="icon-google-plus"  onmouseenter="gmail()" onmouseleave="Mouseva3()"><p id="gma">nnnnnnn@gmail.com</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="icon-phone" onmouseenter="telefono()" onmouseleave="Mouseva2()"><p id="fono">1111111</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="icon-skype" onmouseenter="email()" onmouseleave="Mouseva1()"><p id="mail">nnnnnnnnn@hotmail.com</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="icon-whatsapp" onmouseenter="celular()" onmouseleave="Mouseva()"><p id="celu">11111111</p></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Sé que hay una forma para usar sólo una función para onmouseenter y una sola para onmouseleave, seguramente usando 'this', pero no puedo comprender cómo se hace?

Comment: ¿Que quieres conseguir exactamente?

Answer (score 1):

Con el siguiente script al pasar el mouse por encima de la lista de iconos sociales ara mostrar el texto que se encuentra oculto:

```
  $("#social li").on('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).find('p').css("display", "inline-block");
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).find('p').css("display", "none")
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ly9no4qw/

Comment: por favor añade una explicación a tu respuesta, solo poner un fragmento de código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: muchas gracias punto negativo, si es por que no he sido preciso en cuanto a redaccion y explicacion lo merece pero el codigo puede ser una posible solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo mismo con CSS y mejorarías un pelín el rendimiento. 
Sería algo como:

```
#social li p{
    display: none;
}
#social li:hover p{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Con esto se hace lo que con javascript pero sin tocar el [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) y puedes usar otros estilos para tal vez crear una animación en colores o tamaños.

Como observación, por sintaxis en HTML  los elementos `<a>` no pueden contener elementos `<p>` usa `<span>` en su lugar.

[Animaciones CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)